# How to run Django in development on EC2 so that it is accessible to the internet?

Tags: django, amazon-ec2

I have Django app. It's running on an EC2. The EC2 has a private IP address and an elastic public IP address.

I want the web app to be available locally as well as Developer's IP address which is outside the network.

Let's define these three IP addresses as:

```
EC2_PRIVATE_IP
EC2_PUBLIC_IP
DEVELOPER_IP
```

So what I did was ran on the EC2:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Went into my EC2 security settings, and opened up inbound and outbound port 8000 to DEVELOPER_IP.

Then asked Developer to go to the EC2_PUBLIC_IP address on his browser.

Unfortunately that doesn't work as he gets the error:

```
Gateway Timeout: can't connect to remote host
```

## Update #1

I previously tried:

```
python manage.py runserver {EC2_PUBLIC_IP}:8000
```

But I got the error:

```
Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to.
```

Comment: does it make a difference to bind to public IP? `python manage.py runserver public.ip.here:8000`?

Comment: I did. See update #1.

Comment: @JPN Are you sure you've setup the [settings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html) right?

Comment: Yup...it works fine locally.

Comment: I don't understand the `Gateway Timeout` error, are you using a Load Balancer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to open up the port on Windows Firewall as well!

Comment: This answer should be at the top and upwoted about a zillion times. This is the second time I wasted more than an hour because I forgot that my own firewall (on my local machine rather than ec2 instance) is blocking.

Answer (score 8):

The server should be started with below url

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

In EC2 security settings add following in INBOUND settings

```
HTTP TCP 8000 0.0.0.0/0
```

Then you should be accessing this machine with URL

```
http://EC2_PUBLIC_IP:8000
```

If you want to access the url as

```
http://EC2_PUBLIC_IP
```

then run your webserver on port 80 and accordingly change the EC2 security settings.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your firewall is not blocking anything.

Try

```
iptable -F
```

That will delete all your firewall rules on the machine itself.

Edit: However, you should not use it. If want to add a port to your firewall use the following commend if you're running redhat based distros (e.g centos, rhel)

```
system-config-firewall
```

If it not there, try to install it

```
# yum install system-config-firewall # run it after becoming a root
```

Answer (score 1):

All answers here give a solution, I want to post this for completeness.

By default, the runserver command starts the development server on the internal IP at port 8000.

If you want to change the server’s port *(the standar port for internet access is 80)*, pass it as a command-line argument. For instance, this command starts the server on port 80:

> $ python manage.py runserver 80

*Note: You don't want users have to type **:port_number** after the url in the browser. Another thing is you might not be the owner of the host machine, so you might not have access to configure firewall settings to allow others ports than  80.*

If you want to change the server’s IP, pass it along with the port. So to listen on all public IPs (useful if you want to show off your work on other computers on your network), use:

> $ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80

The documentation on all you need to know about development server can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-runserver).

Answer (score 0):

Delete all rules from your outbound security group and replace with an "all traffic" permissive rule.

Your machine is getting the inbound packet but its reply is getting dropped by the security filter.  Your dev's box is going to be sending a packet in with a [(semi-) arbitrary source port number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).

(Also, you can't bind to the public address on the EC2 instance as that's translated from the private address by routing infrastructure, so it's not actually "on" your box.)

Comment: Just tried that...I get "No data received ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Comment: Is that different from what you were getting before?

Comment: Yes. I was getting "Gateway Timeout: can't connect to remote host before."

Comment: That sounds like progress.  There are several reasons why you might be getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, but I think it's a good bet that you've got your EC2 instance and networking set up to allow access into it now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding firewall rules that will allow traffic to port 8000/Other

You will have to run the development server such that it listens to requests on all interfaces and not just the local one

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

or any other port you may choose

Answer (score 0):

Leave the Django app as to run locally and try to install [nginx](http://nginx.org/) in the ec2 instance and proxy the trafic on port 80 to localhost:8000.
Something like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.yoursite.com;
client_max_body_size 1000M;

location / {
proxy_pass_header Server;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
proxy_connect_timeout 1000;
proxy_read_timeout 1000;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/; # This is the trick !
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Connection '';
proxy_http_version 1.1;
chunked_transfer_encoding off;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
}

}
```

You can add the control to serve only for the Developers IP.
Nginx is a lightweight, FAST, SECURE, & SCALABLE Web/Proxy server. The world’s busiest websites use NGINX !
It will run as service, it will listen for all traffic coming from, outgoing to the external world (Internet) and in your case, you would want to tell it to listen for web (port 80) traffic, and redirect it to your Django app (running on port 8000); It is really a nice idea, it is transparent, and, if well tuned, it will empower up your website !
Furthermore, Nginx is very suitable for application delivery for web and mobile. The installation and configuration of nginx is very easy, and you should integrate something similar to the above example to it in order to get your app open to Internet.